# Cannot display array in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

When i press the `<TouchableOpacity>` Button, i want the value 'abc' to be appended to the array selectedTags and then `<Text> {this.list()} </Text>` will print out my array.
But now when i press the Button, nothing display out.

Can anybody know what is the problem with my code?

```
export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          selectedTags: []
        }
  }

  list() {
  return this.state.selectedTags.map(function(tags, i){
    return(
      <View key={i}>
        <Text>{tags.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.state.selectedTags.push('abc')} key = {1} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Button </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

          <Text> {this.list()} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you never call setState, which would trigger re-render of your component.

instead of using:

```
onPress={() => this.state.selectedTags.push('abc')}
```

try:

```
onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTags: this.state.selectedTags.concat('abc')})}
```

Comment: why use concat instead of push??

Comment: because `push` change the array but does not return anything. `concat` does not change the array but return a new array with the value provided added at the end of the new array. So in order to assign the new `selectedTags` attribute I need to use concat

Answer (score 1):

The function list only push data in array but does not rerender the view, todo so you have to use **setState** or **forceUpdate**.

You can implement the onpress function like this.

```
onPress = () =>{
  this.state.selectedTags.push("abc");
  this.setState({selectedTags : this.state.selectedTags});
}
```